# Is there a way to use something similar as getClass.getMethod in J2ME?

Tags: design-patterns, java-me, state

i am looking to implement a sort of asynchronous state machine in a project, and for a part of that i was looking for a way to store in a controller a list of methods to execute when it is ready.

Do you guys know a way to do that ?

A colleague thought of using an interface that we would implement inline and put the relevant code in the implemented method of the object but i was wondering if it was doable in a more simple way.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: In Java, functions are not first class citizens, so whenever you need to treat a function as an object you'll need an encapsulating object (aka [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), like in `Runnable`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what we did in the end :

```
    // /////////////////////////////////
// STATE MACHINE SECTION //
// /////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * State abstract class to use with the state machine
     */
    private abstract class State {

        private ApplicationController applicationController;

        public State() {}

        public State(ApplicationController ac) {
            this.applicationController = ac;

        }

        public abstract void execute();

        public ApplicationController getApplicationController() {
            return applicationController;
        }


    }

    /**
     * The next states to execute.
     */
    private Vector nextStates; //Initialized in the constructor

    private boolean loopRunning = false;

    /**
     * Start the loop that will State.execute until there are no further 
     * step in the current flow.
     */
    public void startLoop() {

        State currentState;
        loopRunning = true;

        while(!nextStates.isEmpty()) {
            currentState = (State) nextStates.firstElement();
            nextStates.removeElement(currentState);
            currentState.execute();
        }

        loopRunning = false;
    } 


    /**
     * Set the next state to execute and start the loop if it isn't running.
     * @param nextState 
     */
    private void setNextState(State nextState) {
        this.nextStates.addElement(nextState);
        if(loopRunning == false)
            startLoop();
    }


public void onCallbackFromOtherSubSystem() {
        setNextState(new State() {

            public void execute() {
                try {
                        functionTOExecute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.f(01, "Exception - ", errorDetails, e);
                }   
            }
        });


}
```